# Dynamic buttons - Open file, read and insert text into corresponding column

Tags: python, pyqt, python-3.5, pyqt5

My code dynamically creates a certain amount of buttons given by users input from a QlineEdit box marked self.numberLine. Each button will open file dialog to allow user to specify a file which it searches file then inserts text into the corresponding QlineEdit. The issue I am having is that I can't identify which button is being pressed, so I can't fill the corresponding columns QLineEdit fields.

I have it working somewhat, but when I click the 2nd button it just adds to the 1st column, instead of 2nd column

The clear button does nothing

Example:
if user inputs '3' in numberLine widget and clicks 'ok', it will create 3 columns of widgets, which the top widget will be the button that opens a file dialog for user. The other widgets beneath are the QlineEdit entries

On a side note, when the user changes their number, it creates the right amount of columns, but it doesn't insert anything when I select the file to be searched.

Any clue what I am missing?

Image

[image]

```
    spacer1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    spacer2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)

    self.hbutton.addItem(spacer1)
    self.hbutton.addItem(spacer2)
    self.hboxlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.hboxlayout0 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.hboxlayout1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.hboxlayout2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.hboxlayout3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.hboxlayout4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.hboxlayout5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

    self.gridLayout_12.addLayout(self.hbutton, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    self.gridLayout_12.addLayout(self.hboxlayout, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    self.gridLayout_12.addLayout(self.hboxlayout0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    self.gridLayout_12.addLayout(self.hboxlayout1, 2, 1, 1, 1)
    self.gridLayout_12.addLayout(self.hboxlayout2, 3, 1, 1, 1)
    self.gridLayout_12.addLayout(self.hboxlayout3, 4, 1, 1, 1)
    self.gridLayout_12.addLayout(self.hboxlayout4, 6, 1, 1, 1)
    self.gridLayout_12.addLayout(self.hboxlayout5, 7, 1, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.addLineEdit)

    self.numberLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    self.numberLine.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 16777215))
    self.numberLine.setObjectName("self.numberLine")
    self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.numberLine)
    self.Array = []
    self.PDiffEntryList = []

def clearLayout(self):
    # del self.Array[:]
    while  self.hboxlayout0.count():
        child =  self.hboxlayout.takeAt(0)
        child1 = self.hboxlayout0.takeAt(0)
        child2 = self.hboxlayout1.takeAt(0)
        child3 = self.hboxlayout2.takeAt(0)
        child4 = self.hboxlayout3.takeAt(0)
        child5 = self.hboxlayout4.takeAt(0)
        child6 = self.hboxlayout5.takeAt(0)
        if child.widget():
            child.widget().deleteLater()
        if child1.widget():
            child1.widget().deleteLater()
        if child2.widget():
            child2.widget().deleteLater()
        if child3.widget():
            child3.widget().deleteLater()
        if child4.widget():
            child4.widget().deleteLater()
        if child5.widget():
            child5.widget().deleteLater()
        if child6.widget():
            child6.widget().deleteLater()

def addLineEdit(self):
    try:
        self.clearLayout()
        self.FileButton = {}
        for i in range(int(self.numberLine.text())):
            self.FileButton[i] = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.FileButton[i].setText('File')
            self.FileButton[i].setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
            self.hboxlayout.addWidget(self.FileButton[i])
            self.FileButton[i].clicked.connect(lambda i=i: self.openfile(i))

            self.le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            self.le.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
            self.hboxlayout0.addWidget(self.le)

            self.le1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            self.le1.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
            self.hboxlayout1.addWidget(self.le1)

            self.le2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            self.le2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
            self.hboxlayout2.addWidget(self.le2)

            self.le3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            self.le3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
            self.hboxlayout3.addWidget(self.le3)

            self.le4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            self.le4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
            self.hboxlayout4.addWidget(self.le4)

            self.le5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            self.le5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
            self.hboxlayout5.addWidget(self.le5)
            self.PDiffEntryList.append(self.le)
    except:
        print('')
def searchfile(self,dir):
    try:
        with open(dir) as f:
            content = f.readlines()

            # # Main Info - Ps, Pd, Ts
            MainList = content[44].split()
            RPM = str(round(float(MainList[0]), 2))
            Ps = str(round(float(MainList[1]), 2))
            Ts = str(round(float(MainList[2]), 2))
            Pd = str(round(float(MainList[3]), 2))
            Ratio = str(round(Pd / Ps, 2))
            DiffP = str(round(Pd - Ps, 2))
            self.input(i)
    except:
        print('Only out files')
def input(self,i):
    if i == 0:
        print('0')
    elif i == 1:
        print('1')
def openfile(self,i):
    filename = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Choose file')
    dir = filename[0]
    directory = os.path.split(dir)[0]
    self.searchfile(dir,i)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of weird things you are doing. For example, not sure why you are declaring "i" a global or what variable names you are choosing. To address your main question though, you are iterating through a for loop where you create an object with the same name over and over again.

```
 try:
        self.clearLayout()
        self.file_buttons = {}
        for i in range(int(self.numberLine.text())):
            self.file_buttons[i] = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
```

Now you can refer to self.file_buttons[i] for any changes you want to make to the button, but it is actually being stored as a separate object each time. The same applies for all of the Line Edit variables that you create.

In general, you seem to be creating the same objects over and over gain and just writing out different names (object1, object2, etc.). That's a good opportunity to use an array or a dictionary to iterate through and create all of those. It will make it easier to keep track of what is going on and much more flexible.

Comment: The global is just something I added but forgot to take out, as for the same objects being created in an array, are you referring to the QLineEdits? If the user puts 3 as a number, and I wanted to access the 2nd button, would I use  an, If self.file_buttons[2].clicked:  to get the second button?

Comment: I followed the code you provided and its doing the same thing.
        if self.FileButton[1]:
            print('1')
        elif self.FileButton[2]:
            print('2') 
When I click first button it prints '1' like it should, but when pressing second button it prints '1'

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code or file a new one? Hard to know exactly what is going on otherwise

Comment: Sorry, thought I did, I updated it. The main problem i'm having is the def input(self, i) function, this is where I want to know which button is clicked and depending on button do something, right now I have it as i == #, I tried if self.FileButton[0].clicked, it does same thing

Comment: The only place I'm seeing you call self.input is in the function searchfile in which you never actually define what "i" is, so I'm not sure what you is happening/what you expect. Furthermore, you are still going to have the same issue as with FileButton for all of your "self.le" variables. My recommendation would be to go through some PyQt tutorials and python programming tutorials to get a sense of what well written code looks like, then re-assess your particular problem and post a simplified version as a new question.

Comment: Is there not a way to see which button was clicked? When it goes to the openfile function, how come 'i' doesn't exist, when I defined it using lambda?